# Datatype/structure to store timezone offset in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, timezone, sqldatatypes

Which would be the proper datatype/structure to store timezone offsets in MySQL? I just want to store the numeric value (the city and country are obviously stored in other columns).

Examples:

- -5:00 Guayaquil, ECU
- -4:30 Caracas, VEN
- 0:00 Some city
- 2:00 Bonn, GER

Comment: If you're only storing the "numeric value" you're not actually storing the time zone, you're only storing the time zone offset.  There's a big difference, especially if you're dealing with future dates where the offset may change at any time due to political reasons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use [`TIME`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/time.html). It's the right data type for the task: you have formatting and [calculations](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html) are available. Moreover, according to the docs, `TIME` is also supposed to be used as a result of differences between two moments, which is what Timezones are in fact.

From the docs:

> MySQL retrieves and displays TIME values in 'HH:MM:SS' format (or
>   'HHH:MM:SS' format for large hours values). TIME values may range from
>   '-838:59:59' to '838:59:59'. The hours part may be so large because
>   the TIME type can be used not only to represent a time of day (which
>   must be less than 24 hours), but also elapsed time or a time interval
>   between two events (which may be much greater than 24 hours, or even
>   negative).