# How to store users timezone in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, date, time

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Datatype/structure to store timezones in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7586819/datatype-structure-to-store-timezones-in-mysql)

I'll be storing only UTC times in my database, and want to convert the timestamps to a user's local time using PHP.

My question is, what is the best way to store the users timezone in the database?

IE: -400, -4, -4:00

With that said, I know how to do the math manually:

```
$utc_time = strtotime("2011-10-02 23:00:00");
$my_time = $utc_time - 14400;

echo date($timeformat, $mytime);
```

My problem is, with the user's timezone being pulled from the database, I don't know whether I'll be adding or subtracting seconds. That's where I run into the problem of trying to figure out how to save the timezone so that I can calculate the offset.

I can save the timezone as "-14400", but using the above example, I can't just combine the two strings to do the math for me using the - sign:

```
$my_time = $utc_time.$timezone;
```

So... how do I save the timezone properly to get the math done?

Comment: Why don't you just do the math like:
$my_time = $utc_time - $timezone*3600;

Comment: So if I save it as TIME, how is the math done?

Comment: @JoostvanDoorn- I don't know if it's + or - ... that's the issue I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: The data type it can be VARCHAR -> you can do math with string, since it represents a decimal, octal, binary or hexa.

Comment: Basically if you store it as timezone UTC -1 = -1 then you should do
$my_time = $utc_time + $timezone*3600; As said above you can calculate with strings. What you're actually doing in your statement is creating a string which contains "{the UTC time}{your timezone}" as the dot (.) is used to glue two strings together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The timezone in one location isn't always the same - for example, the UK is BST (GMT + 1) between March and October. Use one of the timezones supported by PHP:

http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

If you do go ahead using numbers, either store them as hours or minutes. Store timezones west of UTC/GMT as negative numbers. For example, the US East Coast would be `-5` (hours) or `-300` (minutes) - assuming it's 5 hours behind.

Then, add this to the timestamp - the negative or positive will handle the rest.

```
// for 5 hours behind when stored as hours (-5)
$now = time() + ($offset * 60 * 60);
// for 5 hours behind when stored as minutes (-300)
$now = time() + ($offset * 60);
```

Comment: I think the line `$now = time() + ($offset * 60);` will be `$now = time() + ($offset * 60 * 60);`

Answer (score 2):

timezone string would be better than the offset or difference in hours
because some timezones are subject of changes

http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php

for date/time math:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php

stop using php functions, oop classes are much better!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than storing it as a string, store it as a number? Then you can simply add that number to the timestamp. (The number can be negative for timezones which would subtract.)