# What format should I use to store a user's preferred time zone in a MySQL table?

Tags: php, mysql, database, datetime, timezone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Datatype/structure to store timezones in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7586819/datatype-structure-to-store-timezones-in-mysql)
>   [How to store users timezone in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7679794/how-to-store-users-timezone-in-mysql)

I see two options -- an offset from UTC or GMT, or storing the time zone in a string like "Asia/Seoul".  I get that the offset method doesn't account for time changes, so I won't use that, but for some reason it seemed a bit odd to store a user's time zone just typed out in English.  Is there some other time zone format that I overlooked?

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to use PHP then a timezone string like `Asia/Seoul` will be easier to work with especially when you're using the [`DateTime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) suite of classes (especially [`DateTimeZone`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php)).